# Google Web Font "Drod Arabic Kufi" not work with Safari Browser

Tags: css, fonts, safari, google-font-api, google-webfonts

I used Google web font "Droid Arabic Kufi" in my web application, the font works on `Google Chrome`, `Mozilla Firefox` and `Microsoft Edge`, But it does not work on the `Apple Safari` .. What I'm doing is:

1- Import the font in the top of the `CSS` file:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/droidarabickufi.css);
```

2- Used it, For Example:

```
body {
font-family: 'Droid Arabic Kufi', sans-serif;
background-color: #f8fafb;}
```

Why `Safari` browser does not recognize the font like the other browsers does?

Comment: Could you put up a workin snippet with some text so we can try it for ourselves on various systems.

Comment: @AHaworth Thanks, I solved the issue, Check the answer

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by using the following steps:

1- Download `.ttf` format file and include it to my project files.

2- Use the `@Font-face` attribute property to manually define font name and giving source file.

```
@font-face {
font-family: Droid Arabic Kufi;
src: url(../../fonts/Droid.Arabic.Kufi.ttf);}
```

3- Access the defined font in any element required with Font-family property.

```
body {
font-family: 'Droid Arabic Kufi', sans-serif;
background-color: #f8fafb;}
```

Using this way the font work perfect on the following browser:

- Apple Safari
- Google Chrome
- Microsoft Edge
- Mozila Firefox
- Opera